# regular expression to match condition of character if exists should always be followed by a pattern

Tags: regular-expressions

I need a regular expression with the condition that ..if there is an occurrence of character | one time ;the pattern immediately following is ARGS or URL

For example

```
abcd
ab|ARGS
cd|URL
```

etc is valid

```
abcd|
ab||ARGS
ab|cd
```

etc are invalid (should not match )

Comment: And what have you tried so far, what regex resources have you already checked?

Comment: Tried   .*\|(ARGS|URL).*       which doesnt match abcd though

Comment: @AnoopPAlias If I read your requirements, it shouldn't match abcd| ? (And your valid examples contradicts your written requirements)

Comment: @Reaces - Yes it shouldnt match abcd| .In the example the first three are the matching ones and the 2nd set of 3 are the invalid ones or that should not match . abcd1 comes in 2nd set .

Answer (score 2):

Very old post, but it still may help someone.

The following regex worked for me:

```
^[^\|]*(\|ARGS|\|URL)?[^\|]*$
```

([test it on regexr.com](https://regexr.com/46dsh))

I added the `|` to the ARGS and URL string, and forbid them before or after.